# Line breaks not counted as 2 characters towards the length of a string

Tags: c#

I am wondering why \n is not counted as 2 characters when determining the length of a string in C#

EX:
This is a test comment\nSample text test 123456\nadssssssssss\n\nasdasdasda\nasdadadadad\nasadad\nasada\n\n\nLast paragraph\n12345\nTest

The above string contains 136 characters, but the Length property of the String object I store the string in counts \n as 1 chartacter, and reports the string as 124 characters long.

I want to extract a substring based on pre calculated start and lenght markers. The markers were created counting \n as two characters.
How could I do the equivilent of the following in C#

```
select SUBSTRING('This is a test comment\nSample text test 123456\nadssssssssss\n\nasdasdasda\nasdadadadad\nasadad\nasada\n\n\nLast paragraph\n12345\nTest',1,136);
```

I can't use substring since my lenght offset of 136 is outside the boundaries of the c# representation of the string.

Comment: If you literally meant `\n` (Backslash and a 'n', rather than the newline character) you need to use verbatim string literals or `\\n`.

Comment: The strings are created from an html textarea, so the \n chars are stored in the DB

Answer (score 9):

`String.Length` *does* include newlines:

```
string test = "1234\n6789\n\nC";

Console.WriteLine(test);
Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", test.Length);
```

Output:

```
1234
6789

C    
Length: 12
```

What you may be missing is that `'\n'` is one character. It represents the newline character (`LF`).  The backslash in a string literal indicates it is an [**Escape Sequence**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

So even though *you* count 136 characters, the `\n` is replaced with a single newline character when it is compiled.

---

Note, depending on where this string is being used, you may want to consider using [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) instead of `\n`.  The *true* newline on Windows is `"\r\n"`, or `CR LF`. While many controls, etc. will handle the `\n` fine, files and other things may expect `\r\n`.

```
string test = "Welcome to" + Environment.NewLine + "StackOverflow!";
```

Comment: +1. More obvious maybe to check `"\n".Length` which is 1, and `Environment.NewLine.Length` which is 2.

Answer (score 1):

It does not substract the \n characters, it just counts one line break \n as one character, which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You don't count the `'\'` It is there to tell the system that the character to the right is something *'Special'*. In your case it happens to be a line break `\n`. It could also be a tab `\t`, carriage return `\r`...
So the math is correct.